# Contar los elementos que se encuentran dentro de un objeto

Tags: javascript

No logro obtener la cantidad que se encuentran dentro de counter, es decir debería mostrarme dos, ya que tengo *counter_1* y *counter_2* cómo hago para siempre obtener la cantidad y posteriormente poder recorrer con un ciclo for.

```js
counter = {
counter_1: {
counter_name: 'contador1'
},
counter_2: {
counter_name: 'contador2'
}
}
```

YA INTENTÉ CON

```
alert(counter.length);
```

Comment: @BetaM si exacto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Declara un vector vacio que posteriormente llenaremos con las claves
  de cada elemento interno
- Iteramos al objeto por medio del ciclo [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in)
- Hacemos un push al vector vacio con los valores que con el ciclo obtuvimos

Lo anterior nos dará este resultado:

```
["counter_1", "counter_2"]
```

- Finalmente para obtener la cantidad hacemos uso de la propiedad `length` al vector recién llenado

**Ejemplo completo**

```js
    counter = 
    {
      counter_1: {
        counter_name: 'contador1'
      },
      counter_2: {
        counter_name: 'contador2'
      }
    }
    
    let conteo = []
    for(let elemento in counter) {
      conteo.push(elemento)
    }
    
    console.log(conteo)
    console.log(`El total de elementos es: ${conteo.length}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un bucle for in:

```
var j=0;
for(var i in counter){
    j++;
}
alert(j);
```

O el método keys de Object:

```
var n=Object.keys(counter);
alert(n.length);
```